# Performing CRUD operations on front end in wordpress

Tags: plugins, database, javascript, mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to create a system where I can perform CRUD operations on a wordpress front end. I've seen a few plugins with shortcodes that allow this, so that is one possibility. However, ideally, I would like to use javascript (i.e. when a button is pressed somehow make some call to the SQL database and update a column in the table, etc.).

Is it possible to have dynamic javascript like this on a wordpress site?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you aware of the REST API and making HTTP requests in JS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do.
Try using ajax, or better? using wordpress rest api

Ajax method: need register your function and action to do

Simple example:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action() {
    return json_encode('hello word');
}
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var data = {
        'action': 'my_action'
    };
    jQuery.post(ajax_url, data, function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });
});
```

More info for ajax:
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Wordpress rest api: need to register a route

very simple example:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'yourName/v1', '/myroute', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'my_function',
  ) );
} );

function my_function( $data ) {
  return 'Hello World';
}
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.post('/wp-json/yourName/v1/myroute', function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });
});
```

More info:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: This is the old way of doing things, you should update the answer to include mention of the REST API

Comment: Yeah right. But Ajax is still widely used

Comment: both methods are intended for AJAX, I've amended the answer to have a jQuery example, and switch the REST API from GET to POST so that they match